# How to get the id or url of the image in an image post?

Tags: post-formats, images, tax-query

I have a bunch of image posts and I'd like to get the ID of those images I didn't set a featured image so I can use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to get the urls of various sizes of those images.

This is what I created:

```
$img_posts = get_posts( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'post-format-image',
          'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )
) );

foreach( (array) $img_posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
   $imgID = get_img_id();
    //img sources
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgID, 'thumb');
    $reg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgID, 'large');
    $big = wp_get_attachment_image_src($imgID);
}
```

The `get_img_id` function on the 6th to lastline, which is probably the source of all of my problems, looks like this:

```
function get_img_id() {
        global $post;
        $id = intval( $post->ID );
        $imgID = get_children( array(
                'post_parent' => $id,
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'numberposts' => 1
            ) );

    return $imgID;
}
```

When I do this I get no errors or output. If I add something like `the_content` to the array instead it functions properly.

UPDATE: Per @TheDeadMedic's suggestion I tried this:

```
$img_posts = get_posts( array(
    'cat' => '2',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'post-format-image',
          'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )
) );
foreach( (array) $img_posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $img_id = get_img_id();
    var_dump ($img_id);
}
```

This returned

```
array
    empty
```

Once per post queried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$imgID` is an array of post objects. Instead of:

```
return $imgID;
```

You need:

```
return $imgID ? key( $imgID ) : 0;
```

Since `get_children` returns an array of posts indexed by their ID, you can simply use `key` to return the value of the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the line in my `get_img_id`  function as you suggested. To test I did `$imgID = get_img_id(); echo $imgID;` I got the a zero, followed by the name of the post. I tried different numbers but I just got that number and the name of the post:(

Comment: Go back to what you had before, then `var_dump( $imgID )` & update your question with what you get.

Comment: I updated the question with the result.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that there aren't actually any images attached to the post (at least not in the database). Have you tried creating a new post & uploading & attaching another image?

Comment: Facepalm! Why didn't I think of that basic troubleshooting step?? Your answer (`return $imgID ? key( $imgID ) : 0;`) works with the new post.